# Apache Solr replication fails with "Unable to download" error

Tags: solr, lucene

I am facing an issue with Apache Solr replication while trying to create a replica manually. I am using Apache Solr version 8.11.2 in SolrCloud mode. The Solr indexes are working fine and the upstream application is able to respond to search queries and accept updates to the index process was previously working fine

I need to add another replica on a second Sor node and while doing so I am encountering an error.

Error message from Solr logs with application specific information removed:

```
ERROR (recoveryExecutor-11-thread-1-processing-n:<server ip> :7575_solr x:<replica> c:<collection> s:shard1
r:core_node22) [c:<collection> s:shard1 r:core_node22 x:<replica name>] o.a.s.c.RecoveryStrategy Error while trying to recover => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Replication for recovery failed.

        at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.replicate(RecoveryStrategy.java:255)

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Replication for recovery failed.

        at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.replicate(RecoveryStrategy.java:255) ~[?:?]

        at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.doSyncOrReplicateRecovery(RecoveryStrategy.java:683) ~[?:?]

        at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.doRecovery(RecoveryStrategy.java:339) ~[?:?]

        at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.run(RecoveryStrategy.java:318) ~[?:?]

        at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:180) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar

:4.1.5]

        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_141]

        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_141]

        at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_141]

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_141]

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_141]


     x:ydm_task_shard1_replica_n21 c:ydm_task s:shard1

r:core_node22) [c:<collection> s:shard1 r:core_node22 x:<replica name>] o.a.s.h.ReplicationHandler Index fetch failed  => org.apache.solr.

common.SolrException: Unable to download _44ljt.cfe completely. Downloaded 0!=479

        at org.apache.solr.handler.IndexFetcher$FileFetcher.cleanup(IndexFetcher.java:1863)

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to download _44ljt.cfe completely. Downloaded 0!=479

        at org.apache.solr.handler.IndexFetcher$FileFetcher.cleanup(IndexFetcher.java:1863) ~[?:?]

        at org.apache.solr.handler.IndexFetcher$FileFetcher.fetch(IndexFetcher.java:1743) ~[?:?]

        at org.apache.solr.handler.IndexFetcher$FileFetcher.fetchFile(IndexFetcher.java:1718) ~[?:?]

        at org.apache.solr.handler.IndexFetcher.downloadIndexFiles(IndexFetcher.java:1109) ~[?:?]

        at org.apache.solr.handler.IndexFetcher.fetchLatestIndex(IndexFetcher.java:619) ~[?:?]

        at org.apache.solr.handler.IndexFetcher.fetchLatestIndex(IndexFetcher.java:384) ~[?:?]

        at org.apache.solr.handler.ReplicationHandler.doFetch(ReplicationHandler.java:458) ~[?:?]

        at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.replicate(RecoveryStrategy.java:252) ~[?:?]

        at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.doSyncOrReplicateRecovery(RecoveryStrategy.java:683) ~[?:?]

        at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.doRecovery(RecoveryStrategy.java:339) ~[?:?]

        at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.run(RecoveryStrategy.java:318) ~[?:?]

        at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:180) ~[metrics-core-4.1.5.jar

:4.1.5]

        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_141]

        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_141]

        at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_141]

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_141]

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_141]
```

Here are the details and troubleshooting steps I have already tried:

Solr configuration is working fine for normal usage.

The existing collection is in a good state, and replication factor and shard allocation are correctly configured.

There is sufficient disk space and available memory on all nodes.

Network connectivity is established, and there are no firewall or network-related issues.

Solr version is the recent (8.11.2), and no recent changes have been made to the configuration. We did update the index configuration recently for adding a few fields ot the index and ran a full reindexing. The replica went into recovery state at first during re-indexing. After reindexing was finished and the leader was in normal low load state, we tried deleting the "recovering" replicas and recreating them.
However when we add replica each time they get stuck and we keep seeing the above error repeated in Solr logs.

I have checked the Solr logs, but they do not provide any additional useful information regarding the issue.

I have tried creating a replica on different nodes within the Solr cluster, but the problem persists.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Apache Solr replication? Are there any additional steps or configurations that I should consider to troubleshoot this problem?

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

---

Update - We left the newly added replica as is (in recovering state) overnight and eventually (possibly due to lower load from new incoming  data ) the index replica recovered properly.
We still do not understand why theses errors happened and what can be done to fix them faster.